# setting element oninput from javascript array variable

Tags: javascript

I have code akin to the following:

```
// Already existing: var my_elements - an array of elements.
for (var i = 0, len = my_elements.length; i < len; i++){
    my_elements[i].oninput = function(){blue_background(my_elements[i])};
}

function blue_background(my_element){
    my_element.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

The problem with this, however, as far as I can tell, as the array is looped through, by the time the event triggers, [i] is no longer an existing variable and I get an alert of "undefined".

Comment: You have to show all the relevant code so we can reproduce your issue. Add the HTML and any CSS and show us when the code you've posted actually runs.

Comment: change var with let

Comment: As for your specific issue. Change `var i` to `let i` so that you get block level scope

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You should have just enough code to illustrate the error you get without any extra unrelated code. Anyone should be able to run it themselves and get the same result.